# Override the default icon from mat-stepper angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to override the default edit icon from stepper material angular but this don't work.

I try:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
   <mat-step>
      <form>
           <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
                <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
           </ng-template>

    ...

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

In this way my result is:

When the stepper is active/inactive:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/upB0e.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU143.png

There's something special that i have to do?

Stackblitz:
Click in material page. the home icon is not inside the blue circle.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-wxawqh

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8997#issuecomment-384444770

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've created an example where the default edit icon is changed: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-example).

Move your definition of the changed edit icon **outside** of the `<mat-step>...</mat-step` and it should work (tested with latest Angular 7.0.2):

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">

  <!-- change default 'edit' icon -->
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
    <mat-icon>bubble_chart</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>

  <mat-step label="Antes de começar...">
    <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Continuar</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
```

In addition I added some examples for changing the icons of the different steps (check the comments in the Stackblitz). For this to work, you need to add a provider to your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

@Component({
  selector: 'with-material-app',
  templateUrl: './withmaterial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./withmaterial.component.css'],
  providers: [{
    provide: MAT_STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: { displayDefaultIndicatorType: false }
  }]
})
export class WithMaterialComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

and change your `mat-horizontal-stepper` like this:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">

    <!-- change default 'edit' icon -->
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
        <mat-icon>bubble_chart</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- changed step icons -->
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="home">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <mat-step label="Antes de começar..." state="home">
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Continuar</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>

  ...

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

The `ng-template` with `matStepperIcon='xyz'` changes the icon of the `mat-step` with `state="xyz"`.

Comment: If you are not able to import `MAT_STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS`, then try it with `STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the first place you should look for answer is Angular Material documentation and examples.

Overriding icons is described in straightforward way

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#overriding-icons

From docs:

> By default, the step headers will use the create and done icons from
>   the Material design icon set via  elements. If you want to
>   provide a different set of icons, you can do so by placing a
>   matStepperIcon for each of the icons that you want to override. The
>   index, active, and optional values of the individual steps are
>   available through template variables:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
    <mat-icon>insert_drive_file</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
    <mat-icon>done_all</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>

  <!-- Custom icon with a context variable. -->
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="number" let-index="index">
    {{index + 10}}
  </ng-template>

  <!-- Stepper steps go here -->
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: i try equal descripted in the doc

Comment: Your stackblitz works just fine, you just placed your template in wrong place-> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-zh1ffm?file=src/app/withmaterial/withmaterial.component.html

Comment: Thank You. Overriding number helped. Had a scenario where first tab should start from 3

Answer (score 4):

This example works for me:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper color="primary" linear >        
    <!-- Define the edit icon, by default is 'create' -->
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
        <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- Define the number of the step -->                  
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="number" let-index="index">
    {{index+1}}
    </ng-template>

    <!-- Make your steps -->
    <mat-step label="Step 1">
        Stepper 1
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Step 2">
        Stepper 2
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: Is there any way to use different edit icon for each step?

Answer (score 4):

To extend the accepted answer: I wanted to retain the step number rather than replacing the icon.  That's possible using the following:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper >
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index">{{index + 1}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done" let-index="index">{{index + 1}}</ng-template>
  <mat-step>
    <!-- add steps as usual -->
  </mat-step
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to override the icons for each step regardless of the state that the step is in - i.e. so that a given step always displays the same icon, even if it being edited or is already complete. I accomplished this as follows.

In the template:

```
<mat-stepper>
  <ng-template #stepperIcon>
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    ...
  </mat-step>

  <ng-template #stepperIcon>
    <mat-icon>bubble_chart</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <mat-step label="Step 2">
    ...
  </mat-step>
  
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="number" let-index="index">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="matStepperIcons && matStepperIcons[index]"></ng-container>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="matStepperIcons && matStepperIcons[index]"></ng-container>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done" let-index="index">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="matStepperIcons && matStepperIcons[index]"></ng-container>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="error" let-index="index">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="matStepperIcons && matStepperIcons[index]"></ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</mat-stepper>
```

In the component:

```
export class Component implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren('stepperIcon') private matStepperIconViewChildren;

  matStepperIcons: any[];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.matStepperIcons = this.matStepperIconViewChildren.toArray();
  }
}
```

This of course relies on the icon templates being defined in the same order as the steps to which they relate, and having a one-to-one relationship with them.